# Sum the numbers contained in strings inside parentheses

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to get the sum of all the numbers inside the parentheses.  Example:

```
RIZA SMITH (2A/1C)  
LANIE ADAMS (2A)  
STEVE ANDREWS (1A/3C)
```

In this case, 2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 3 yields a total of 9.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. What tool are you using? Do you use a calculator with pen and paper, and you don't know how to use your calculator? Or do you perhaps use another program? Basically, lots of information is missing, and without that, its very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry about that.. I'm using MS Excel and currently doing a worksheet for my church. these are the sample data from the excel sheet given to me. Thanks again..

Comment: Please [*edit*](https://superuser.com/posts/1346381/edit) your question with any additional information. What happens if you have something like `John Doe (1/2)`, is it counted as `0.5` or `1+2`? What about `John Doe (12A)? etc...

Comment: Is 2a just a number and a letter? Or is it a Column and Row?

Comment: Create a macro (VBA function) which extracts and sums all numbers from all cells in a range transferred to it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

**I would like to suggest two steps solution. I'm assuming that you have data in Column A.**

*Write this Array Formula in Cell `B2`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & Fill down.*

```
{=SUM(VALUE(MID(0&A2,LARGE(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1))*ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))+1,1)))}
```

**How it works:**

- Formula assigns each character with its index and then gets numeric value 
  to Sum.
- Formula returns `3` in `B2`, `2` in `B3` & `4` in `B4`
- In Cell `B5` write `=SUM(B2:B4)` you get `9`.

**Note:**

- Formula considers any Bracket whether is `( )`, `[ ]` or `{ }`.
- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.

Comment: a very nice explanation of how the formula works.. really appreciate it. ( :

Comment: Thanks @p._phidot_ your appreciation pumps lots of energy to do better & better.☺